# How to shrink the screen' size on ubuntu 16.04lts (not VM)

Tags: 16.04, unity, display, screen

Is it possible to shrink the screen' size .. or translate the screen to the right , in order to see the entire screen again

[image: the screen]

Comment: so you wanna change your resolution i think, looks like your screen form left side is broken

Comment: not yhe resolution , I want to change the size .. by changing the resolution nothing happened , it's only the icons will be bigger

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do anything to put it on the right side, the only way is reduce the resolution of your screen, but it will get reduced by right side too, not just left side you can change the resolution by going to `Settings > Devices > Display > Resolution`